# Swift: `Type '[String]' does not conform to protocol 'StringLiteralConvertible'`

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am playing with Swift and Xcode. This works in playground:

```
[["1","2"], ["3","4"]][0]
```

But this does not work in Xcode project:

```
enum UnitSystem: Int {
    case Standard = 0
    case Metric = 1
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var unitSystemControl: UISegmentedControl!  //"Standard" and "Metric"
    var units: [[String]]! = nil
    var currentUnitSystem: UnitSystem! = nil
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...
        currentUnitSystem = UnitSystem(rawValue: unitSystemControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
        units = [["ft.", "in."], ["m.", "cm."]][currentUnitSystem.rawValue]
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

I am getting this error: `Type '[String]' does not conform to protocol 'StringLiteralConvertible'`

## Questions:

- How to deal with this error?
- Is there a cleaner/better way to switch out the units on the fly?
- It seems like I don't quite grasp the whole idea of ! and ? types in Swift, is there an easy-to-understand tutorial somewhere?

Thank you!

Comment: The problem was my `var units: [[String]]! = nil`, making it `var units: [String]? = nil` makes it work. The last two questions still stand, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem isn’t related to your use of optionals.  It’s simpler than that.

In your playground, look at the value returned by `[["1","2"], ["3","4"]][0]`.  It’s not a `[[String]]` (an array of arrays of strings).  It’s a `[String]` (the first entry in your array of arrays).

But in your second example, you’re trying to assign this value to a variable that is of type `[[String]]`.  Just change the type of `units` to `[String]`.

Comment: Thanks, I found that a minute after I posted my question :-) Thank you for a prompt response either way!